# boton de pausa/reanudar en comecocos js

Tags: javascript, html

estaba desarrollando el  juego del comecocos en js, basándome en las directrices indicadas en www.w3schools.com.

Mi problema es que tras pulsar el botón de pausa ('spacebar') el manejador de teclado deja de escuchar y, por lo tanto, no hay manera de reanudar el juego.
No entiendo que es lo que estoy haciendo mal

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">

<script>
var myGamePiece;
var paused;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 225, 225);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        if (!paused){
          this.interval =   clearInterval(this.interval);
          paused = true;
        }else{
          this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 200000);
          paused = false;
        }

    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    console.log("hola")
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.moveAngle = 0;
    myGamePiece.speed = 0;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speed= 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speed= -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[32]) {myGameArea.stop()}
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}
</script>

<p>Make sure the gamearea has focus, and use the arrow keys to move the red square around.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias,Edardo

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que al hacer el clearInterval dejas de llamar a la función updateGameArea por lo que, aunque pulses de nuevo el espacio, nunca va a interpretar la pulsación y llamar al método stop.

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir una propiedad paused al objeto myGameArea que indique si el juego está en pausa o no. De esta forma en el método updateGameArea, si el juego está en pausa, únicamente compruebas si se ha pulsado el espacio y si no es así no haces nada.

Mira este ejemplo:

```js
var myGamePiece;
var paused;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 225, 225);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        this.paused = !this.paused;
        document.getElementById('paused').innerHTML = (this.paused ? 'paused' : ' &nbsp; ');
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    paused: false
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    if (myGameArea.paused){
      if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[32]) {myGameArea.stop()}
      return;
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.moveAngle = 0;
    myGamePiece.speed = 0;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speed= 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speed= -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[32]) {myGameArea.stop()}
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startGame()">


<div id="paused"> &nbsp; </div>
<p>Make sure the gamearea has focus, and use the arrow keys to move the red square around.</p>
</body>
```